# Using Return to end the app. Correct?

Tags: c#, methods, return

I have very simple application just in the body of Main method. I have tried to find out different ways of ending the app except for Environment.Exit() but I entirely forgot I can just call return. Is it correct to use it for ending the app if it just run in Main method? I cannot see any problem but I want to learn as much as I can. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, sounds like you're on the right track. It's not clear if you're running a console application, and this code should help highlight.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool keepRunning = true;
    int x = 0;
    while (keepRunning)
    {
        //at some point, flip keepRunning to fall out of the while loop
        if (moon.Color == Blue)
           keepRunning = false;

        if (x > 0) //or some other condition
            return;
    }
   //naturally will fall out of the Main() and terminate the program
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're exiting out due to an error, you really should use `Environment.Exit` with a non-zero argument... documenting what type of error returns which exit code is a good idea, too.

Otherwise, it should be OK to just `return`... but it's really a stylistic choice.

Comment: You can also declare `Main` to return `int`, and return your exit code.  You don't have to call `Environment.Exit`.

Comment: @PDaddy: I wasn't aware that C# let you do that.  Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is OK to return from the Main method.